# Doctrine 2.0 Query Builder Add Methods Overwrite Each Other

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder, doctrine-query

I thought the purpose of the query builder object was to help dynamically build queries.  However, any time I try to use the query builder in this kind of a context, the helper methods overwrite one another.  For example:

```
$object_identifiers_I_need = array("Obj_One", "Obj_Two", "Obj_Three");
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
foreach($object_identifiers_I_need as $object_identifier){
    $qb->add('select', $object_identifier)
}
```

returns only:

```
SELECT Obj_Three ...
```

rather than the desired

```
SELECT Obj_One, Obj_Two, Obj_Three ...
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to add multiple selects without sticking them all in an array in a single call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#expr-classes): All helper methods in QueryBuilder actually rely on a single one: add(). This method is responsible of building every piece of DQL. It takes 3 parameters: $dqlPartName, $dqlPart **and $append (default=false).**

After changing the default behavior of $append to true, this is working much better for me.